# Easy Function to plot equation of abline

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am beginner in R and i have a simple regression. Now i want to plot the equation of the regression line into the plot. The most easiest way. I already tried to get it done by following some ideas here.

```
DICE_Quartal<-read.csv("")
attach(DICE_Quartal)
plot(Preise.Fernbusmarkt ~ Auskunftpflichtige.Unternehmen) + abline(cor_preis_unternehmen, col = "red")
```

Comment: what's wrong w abline exactly?

Comment: abline is correct but i want to plot the equation of it into

Comment: `reg <- lm(Preise.Fernbusmarkt ~ Auskunftpflichtige.Unternehmen, data=DICE_Quartal); abline(reg)`

Comment: but that only plots the line... i want the equation formula as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569288/how-do-i-add-a-regression-line-equation-to-plot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a regression line equation to plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569288/how-do-i-add-a-regression-line-equation-to-plot)

Comment: ok thanks. now i have the r squared...and the equation formula?

Comment: Please fix the question and ensure it asks for what you want and that any code in it is *reproducible* so that anyone else can run it. See the instructions at the top of [tag:r] .